# when php back-end get param values show Array ( [id] => [object Object] ), how to get the real value?

Tags: php, reactjs, server

**index.js**

```
   return (
        <Dropzone
            accept="image/*,audio/*,video/*,.pdf"
            getUploadParams={({file, meta}) => {

                const body = new FormData();
                body.append('fileField', file);
                body.append('id', id);

                console.log(file);
                console.log(id);
                return {url: 'http://localhost/cup/u_upload_img.php', body}
            }}

            onSubmit={handleSubmit}
            InputComponent={Input}
            getFilesFromEvent={getFilesFromEvent}
            submitButtonContent="submit"
        />
    )
```

`index.js` is front page, also I used [react dropzone uploader API](https://react-dropzone-uploader.js.org/docs/quick-start). when I drag files to my broswer.

The `console.log(file)` is okay, and the `console.log(id)`is okay too. Here has a screen shot.

[console.log()](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nKtyp.jpg)

**server.js**

```
<?php
    $json = json_encode($_POST);
    //print_r($json);

    $obj = json_decode($json, true);
    print_r($obj);

    $id = $obj->id;
    echo $id;
```

But I can't accept this id which from front-page, and the network showed like this

`Array ( [id] => [object Object] )`

[network error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IxdbK.jpg)

I want to get this id, but I don't know how to deal with it.

Comment: try to use var_dump in php which will give you complete logs with data types

Comment: result `array (size=1)
  'id' => string '[object Object]' (length=15)`  @ Vikas Kandari

Comment: seems you are receiving wrong data from front end  you need to parse id  properly in JavaScript, make sure you are not putting JavaScript object directly into id which will be set as [object object] ,

Comment: when I change my front code  like this `body.append('id', JSON.stringify(id));`
the back end network will show `Array ( [id] => {"id":"test"} )`

Comment: but another problem is how can I get the "test" value @ Vikas Kandari

Comment: to get the test value in backend simply use body.append('id',id.id); your id variable is a object containing {id:"test"} key pair so to get test value you need to use id.id instead of id also don't need to use json stringify if value is single

Comment: yeah I actually get this in back-end `Array ( [id] => test )`, you are right! so I write code like this `
$json = json_encode($_POST);
$obj = json_decode($json, true);
$id = $obj->id;` but the message said  ` Trying to get property of non-object in` It's very curious @ Vikas Kandari

Comment: try to access value like this in php $id = $obj["id"]

Comment: I just want to reply to you,  but I saw you already give me some suggestions! hahaha you are very good !@   Vikas Kandari

Comment: thanks, these days I still think about this. finally, you save me thank you !!

Answer (score 0):

start from the top server.js

```
var_dump($_POST);        /* an object, right? */

$arr = json_decode($_POST, true);   /* this converts object into an associative array */

foreach($arr as $key=>$val){ echo ($key == 'id') ? $val : '';}   // here you go

/* lazy version without decode() */
foreach($_POST as $value){ foreach($value as $key=>$val){ echo ($key == 'id') ? $val : '';}}
```

As always, there are many other ways to get this value. But you must care about security same time, don't forget it. This code is NOT SECURE, is just clear example, not good practice :)